# Create composable query for many_to_many association

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to create a composable ecto query for listing all `Document` for a specific `Contributor`. I want the api to look something like this:

```
Document
|> Document.for_contributor(contributor)
|> Repo.all()
```

But I'm at a loss as to where to begin. I've been doing composable queries before and in a `has_many` relation where a `Contributor` could have many `Document` I would do something like this:

```
  def for_contributor(query, %Contributor{} = contributor) do
    from(document in query, where: document.contributor_id == ^contributor.id)
  end
```

But I'm not sure how I would go about doing something similar but with a `many_to_many` relation.

What would go in my `for_contributor` function?

```
defmodule MyApp.Document do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  alias MyApp.Contributor

  schema "documents" do
    many_to_many(:contributors, Contributor, join_through: "contributors_documents")
    timestamps()
  end

  def for_contributor(query, %Contributor{} = contributor) do
    # ???
  end
end
```

My join table looks like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateContributorsDocuments do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:contributors_documents, primary_key: false) do
      add :contributor_id, references(:contributors)
      add :document_id, references(:documents)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it more complicated in my head than it needed to be. I solved it with a simple `join`.

```
  def for_contributor(query, %Contributor{} = contributor) do
    from(
      document in query,
      join: c in assoc(document, :contributors),
      where: c.id == ^contributor.id
    )
  end
```